# Interpreting Math GRE chart

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, gre

So in [this data set](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/13965/22511), around 50/245 admitted prospective graduate students from 2009-2012 were part of the top 5% in his/her exam?

[image]

Comment: I think only people who get admissions are included here.

Comment: I didn't sum up the bars, but yes, it seems to be saying that 50 of the admitted international students scored in the top 5% in the math GRE, but only 5 of the admitted domestic students.  Typically schools have a wider pool of international applicants so can set "higher standards" for them.

Comment: Sure.  By the way, I'm not sure it's literally true that most schools get more international applicants than domestic ones, but at the least the international applicant pool tends to be stronger.  This may be due more a result of self-selection, as well as the educational systems in different countries.